# SQLITE: Table names to select from as a subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to select distinct values of one column from many tables at once. The two queries I want to combine are:

1. Select all the appropriate tables:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM sqlite_schema 
WHERE type='table' 
    AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%';
```

2. Select distinct values from one table:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY FROM my_table;
```

I want to run this last query on each table name from the results of the first query. I'm pretty sure it should be possible, but haven't worked it out.

Something like this is what I imagine:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY 
FROM (
    SELECT name
    FROM sqlite_schema 
    WHERE type='table' 
        AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%'
);
```

This combined query throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best that you can do with SQLite is get the sql statement that you need as a string and execute it with the programming language of your choice:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT CATEGORY FROM ' || name, ' UNION ') AS sql
FROM sqlite_schema 
WHERE type='table' AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%';
```

You will get a string like:

```
SELECT CATEGORY FROM table1 
UNION 
SELECT CATEGORY FROM table2 
UNION 
SELECT CATEGORY FROM table3
```

I use `UNION` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/U6goikKq).